# Why this reg file gets rejected by the windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

i'm trying to delete guest account but when i double click on the file or import it from within registry i get "you can only import binary registry files from within the registry editor" in the first case and "the specified file is not a registry file" in the second. Maybe it's because its written for xp, but others suggest it should work. Can you help me?

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\0 00001F5]
"V"=hex:00,00,00,00,b0,00,00,00,02,00,01,00,b0,00, 00,00,0a,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,bc,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,bc,00,00,00 ,70,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
2c,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,00,00,00 ,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,\
01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,00,00,00,00 ,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,\
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,00,00,00,00,00 ,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,00,00,00,00,00,00 ,00,00,00,00,2c,01,00,00,\
08,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,34,01,00,00,04,00,00,00,00 ,00,00,00,38,01,00,00,04,\
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,3c,01,00,00,04,00,00,00,00,00 ,00,00,40,01,00,00,04,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,14,80,90,00,00,00,a0,00,00 ,00,14,00,00,00,44,00,00,\
00,02,00,30,00,02,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,44,00,05,01 ,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,\
00,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,ff,ff,1f,00,01,01,00,00,00 ,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,02,\
00,4c,00,03,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,1b,03,02,00,01,01 ,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,18,00,ff,07,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00 ,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,\
00,00,00,18,00,ff,07,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05 ,20,00,00,00,24,02,00,00,\
01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01

[from here](http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f10/cant-delete-guest-user-account-149096.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the header line. Try this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM\SAM\Domains\Account\Users\000001F5] 
"V"=hex:00,00,00,00,b0,00,00,00,02,00,01,00,b0,00, 00,00,0a,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,bc,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,bc,00,00,00,70,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
2c,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,\
01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,\
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,2c,01,00,00,\
08,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,34,01,00,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,38,01,00,00,04,\
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,3c,01,00,00,04,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,40,01,00,00,04,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,14,80,90,00,00,00,a0,00,00,00,14,00,00,00,44,00,00,\
00,02,00,30,00,02,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,44,00,05,01,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,\
00,00,00,00,02,c0,14,00,ff,ff,1f,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,07,00,00,00,02,\
00,4c,00,03,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,1b,03,02,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,01,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,18,00,ff,07,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,\
00,00,00,18,00,ff,07,0f,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,24,02,00,00,\
01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,01
```

As a sidenote: There was also a space in the name of the key, that has to be removed.

Comment: after i run this code i can't access add or remove user accounts (

Comment: Do you always run code from the internet without having a backup?

Comment: what this <"V"=hex:00,00,00,00,b0...> actually mean? is there any links describing how this hex values works and how to translate it?